# Designing a trait in rust so that implementers can be indexable by Into<IdxType>

Tags: rust, indexing, traits

In rust (rustc 1.66.0), I have a trait `Foo` that defines a container that holds type T and can be indexed with type Coord:

```
pub trait Foo: Index<Self::Coord> {
    type Elem;
    type Coord;
}
```

So far so good. Problem is I would like to make it so that implementing types can be indexed by anything that is `Into<Self::Coord>` but I don't know how to express this while keeping a compiler happy. For example if I try

```
pub trait Foo: Index<dyn Into<Self::Coord>> {
    type Elem;
    type Coord;
}
```

I get

> the trait `Into` cannot be made into an object
>
> the trait cannot be made into an object because it requires `Self: Sized`
>
> for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically; for more information visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety

Comment: You won't be able to make this trait object trait while also requiring it be indexable by `Into<T>`. This is because the object would need to construct a vtable with a function for every type of `K where K: Into<T>`. I would just use your first trait and call `.into()` manually. Or alternatively, you could make a wrapper struct that goes around your `dyn Foo<...>` which can perform that conversion.

Comment: From a first look, it looks like you will need `for<T>` to implement that. However maybe there's a workaround.

Comment: If you can wrap containers in a local type, you could do something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=702cbcd5a65571135e8d1eb4c098e448).